# Android Low Battery Level

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, batterylevel

I am writing an application to **stop a a service** during **low battery**.I am able to do that provided the application is launched and is running and the phone has sufficient battery level.The service is stopped using broadcast receivers when battery level drops and OS prompt is received .However if am **launching the application** in **low battery situation** (say 10%),how do i determine that the phone is currently in low battery and stop the service.

Is it possible to find the **current battery status** and **receive an OS Prompt** that its low battery say at any level below 15%

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to get battery info :-

```
public class Main extends Activity {
  private TextView contentTxt;
  private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);
      contentTxt.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "%");
    }
  };

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    contentTxt = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.monospaceTxt);
    this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, 
    new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
  }
}
```

Now you can get battery info on onReceive method.See below doc

http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Comment: Thank you for your help.Capturing battery level and change in battery level using broadcast receiver is fine.But how do i know if the current level is low battery without me pro grammatically setting the low battery threshold level to 15.Is there any other way to know the value from OS

Answer (score 0):

You just need to register a `BroadcastReceiver` for another action `android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW`. [Here is](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#MonitorLevel) more information on this topic.